# Mixed Content with http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/WebForms.js

Tags: mixed-content, secure-context

I have a web application using ASP.NET  4. It displayed error below : 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/WebForms.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It probably due to below :

But I didn't used above in the project. And I have enable CDN=true at the Script Manager as below.

How should i troubleshoot it or solve it ? Any clues ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load an insecure script (from http) over a secure context (https).

Try to load the script from https like this:

```
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/WebForms.js
```

Comment: Yes, but I actually didn't find above in the code. Is it hide somewhere in asp.net 4 framework ?

Comment: It is working with EnableCDN=false at the ScriptManager.

Comment: Try this instead while keeping CDN=true, 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700852/475159