# Mixed Content issue : calling http from https website using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

Below code is from Tier 1 web application with HTTPS

```
window.JQuery.getScript('../../Scripts/jQuery/jquery.signalRmin.js', function ()     {
 var objsignalrUrl = $('#signalrUrl').val(); //consider my url is http://382.348.48.19
    var connection = $.hubConnection(objsignalrUrl + "/signalr", {
        useDefaultPath: false,
        logging: true
    });
```

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://382.348.48.19/ClientSignalRService/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol….5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22commonhub%22%7D%5D&_=1477391969263'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Getting

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://X382.348.48.19/ClientSignalRService/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol….5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22commonhub%22%7D%5D&_=1477391969263.
>   Failed to start loading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Mixed content blocked" when running an HTTP AJAX operation in an HTTPS page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

Comment: You can't call HTTP from a HTTPS site,in this manner, it's insecure

Comment: You'd still be exposing your users to the same security issues, but you could proxy the requests through your server and at least validate the responses from the 3rd party before passing it back to your users. If the only reason those calls aren't secured is because they're using a self-signed certificate, you can explicitly trust that cert and still make the calls over HTTPS. Just don't leak identifiable data in those exchanges.

Comment: Thanks @Liam . Could you guys  suggest me the possiblities?

Comment: Thanks @Walf, Could you suggest me the possiblities?

Comment: Read the duplicate.

Comment: And make sure one cannot pass arbitrary URLs to your proxy, or your server will just become a vector for malicious users to abuse.

Comment: If that's not enough suggestion then it may be beyond your current capabilities. Your best option is to pressure the 3rd party into using free *Let's Encrypt* certificates. There's really no excuse for lacking encryption, these days.