# JavaScript/jQuery: Setting up IP Geolocation API within CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to using APIs and am having a difficult time making a `GET` request to `IP Geolocation API`. I am not sure if the problem is with my code or with something concerning CodePen (it's probably my code).

I took the JavaScript directly from the example listed on `IP Geolocation API` page. I was going to modify it after seeing it work in action but I couldn't get it work at all. I tried modifying the URL to include both `http://` and `https://`.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
            var table_body = "";
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";
            });
            $("#GeoResults").html(table_body);
        });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="weather">
  <div class="row title">
    <h1>weather</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row icon">

  </div>
  <div id = "GeoResults" class="row temp">
    <p class = "city">City here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

URL to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/mattr8/pen/yXEMRM

API I am trying to use: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page) will help

Comment: because the api uses http and codepen uses https, changing the url to https doesn't work because they don't expose a service over https

Answer (score 0):

Codepen doesn't want to work with ip-api.com because of https.  Because codepen is served over https it will block any requests that are not https.  If you go to http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=? you will see the information you're trying to reach.  If you go to https://ip-api.com/json/?callback=? you will receive an error.

The jsbin example they link to does not use https, so it works fine.

So to fix your issue, create an example on a service or your own machine using http, not https for the request.