# 'Mixed Content' warning when accessing localhost

Tags: django, nginx, https, localhost, mixed-content

I have a website backed by Nginx and Django using HTTPS. I also have a client program that runs locally on my computer, hosted with bottle.py.

The website is accessed with HTTPS and makes Post requests to the client at http://localhost.

I use jQuery for the request to localhost:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5555/command",
        data : data
        type : "POST",
    });
```

I get the following error message from Chrome:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/whatever/' was loaded over HTTPS,
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:5555/'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

This warning is normally useful, but it seems kind of pointless for localhost.

I see two ways of fixing this and would be fine with either:

1) make an exception for localhost so that I can connect to it with http.

2) give the client the ability to handle HTTPS. I'm worried that this is needlessly complicated if I need to create a certificate for this, which would mean extra work whenever it is redeployed.

Note:
this question is similar to this one, but different because I care about localhost in particular and not an arbitrary http website:
["Mixed content blocked" when running an HTTP AJAX operation in an HTTPS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

Comment: It's your browser that's blocking the request, you can't do anything in Django or Nginx to prevent that. If you can't make your client program use `https`, you could use a proxy like https://www.stunnel.org/

Comment: You can't, you know that example.com is your site in this case, but browser doesn't. It follows rules that https sites should do everything over https, also even when you move your local service to https, you will need to have CORS also enabled for the access to work, else browser will then deny the request because of CORS