# Website rendering locally but not on Github server. Problems with RESTfulAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've been making a website on a mock coffee company. The website loads perfectly on my computer, but when I use Github's server a few key factors are missing.

The first and main problem is my RESTful API does not work. Locally it's fine, but on Github it always shows my alert error message that I put in the code. The order coffee function does not work at all because of this.

Second is I have a single image that won't show on Github's server.

My Git repository is up to date, and I've waited over a day to make sure that it had time to load. I'll post some code below that's relevent, but it's probably easiest to check my repository.

https://github.com/austinestrobel/Coffee-ToGo

order.html is the problem page, script.js has my RESTful API and my problem image is in style.css.

**order.html**

```
<div class="container" id="order-background">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h2 class="">Quick</h2>
    <h2 class="">Easy</h2>
    <h2 class="">Quality</h2>
  </div>
</div>`
```

**style.css**

```
#order-background {
  background-image: url('/img/Slider5.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

RESTfulAPI problem.
jQuery GET request to show how it's linked:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/Austin/Coffee/',
  success: function (orders) {
    $.each(orders, function (i, order) {
      addOrder(order);
    });
  },
  error: function () {
    alert('error loading orders');
  }
});
```

### EDIT

Just in case anyone has the same problem, here is the solution I found. If you go to https://reqres.in/, they offer a free RESTful API that works with https. Hopefully that helps someone!

Comment: I looked in the console and found this error message: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://austinestrobel.github.io/Coffee-ToGo/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/Austin/Coffee/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

A found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page) after a quick google

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give that route a go. It wasn't an easy fix like I was hoping, but I at least know what to Google now.
Any tips on the background image that isn't displaying on that page?