# Error - Making call to Api from web app in kubernetes

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-web-api, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to make a call from web app service to web api service of expose type clusterIP in azure kubernetes.

I am getting following error:

> polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an
>   insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://congestion-latest.default/api/galorebridge/test'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served

Comment: So why are you mixing http and https?

Comment: I have hosted my web application in kubernetes with ingress controller and mapped with DNS name which is called using HTTPS. But I am making call from web app to api service(Service - ClusterIP) using service name internally.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, there is nothing to do with Kubernetes services, if you are calling your API service internally.

This error means you try load page through HTTPS, but your API endpoint serves content as HTTP you can't do that.

Either you have to change your API URL to HTTPS, or request page via HTTP.

More information on this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)