# I can not access the link using iframe

Tags: html, apache, amazon-web-services, web, server

I try to access the different URLs from my current domain using iframe but it's not loading into my domain but it's working in the localhost. I used this code **X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM=http://my-secound-url.com** in my .htaccess nothing happened and I used this code **X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://my-secound-url.com** inside my httpd.conf file and I restart the server it's showing the error

**Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

My Iframe code

```
<iframe style="height: 283px;width: 100%;" src="http://secound-url.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And I check my site through developer option console it's showing this message,

**Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-domain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://secound-url.com'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

I using the Amazon EC2 server and my domain is SSL active site. Please help me and give a solution to access the different URL inside my domain

Comment: You need to reference a `HTTPS` version of `http://secound-url.com`. I.e. `https://secound-url.com`

Comment: I did that too also but it's saying the site taking long time to take

Comment: Please read this post, this explains why this is happening: [browser will refuse to load any resources over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507729/11700321) Then try this solution: [Upgrade all HTTP requests to use HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700852/11700321)