# How to deal with insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am very new to coding, and have a problem with my site. I am getting an error message that says:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'ajax-utils.js:34 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://daringtrifles.github.io/courserahtmlcssjavascript/module5realsol/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Here is my AJAX code. Could you guys please tell me where my mistakes are and how I could solve them?

```js
(function(global) {

  // Set up a namespace for our utility
  var ajaxUtils = {};


  // Returns an HTTP request object
  function getRequestObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      return (new XMLHttpRequest());
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      // For very old IE browsers (optional)
      return (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    } else {
      global.alert("Ajax is not supported!");
      return (null);
    }
  }


  // Makes an Ajax GET request to 'requestUrl'
  ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest =
    function(requestUrl, responseHandler, isJsonResponse) {
      var request = getRequestObject();
      request.onreadystatechange =
        function() {
          handleResponse(request,
            responseHandler,
            isJsonResponse);
        };
      request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
      request.send(null); // for POST only
    };


  // Only calls user provided 'responseHandler'
  // function if response is ready
  // and not an error
  function handleResponse(request,
    responseHandler,
    isJsonResponse) {
    if ((request.readyState == 4) &&
      (request.status == 200)) {

      // Default to isJsonResponse = true
      if (isJsonResponse == undefined) {
        isJsonResponse = true;
      }

      if (isJsonResponse) {
        responseHandler(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
      } else {
        responseHandler(request.responseText);
      }
    }
  }


  // Expose utility to the global object
  global.$ajaxUtils = ajaxUtils;


})(window);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Mixed content blocked" when running an HTTP AJAX operation in an HTTPS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
```

`requestUrl` is `http://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json` i guess. You need to change that URL just a bit.

Change your Request URL from

`http://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json`

to

`https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json`.

Just add an "s" to your `http` -> `https`
Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I have another error message coming up now "ajax-utils.js:34 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/module-5-master/snippets/home-snippet.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." Again, there is a problem at line 34. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: ok you have an cors error now. what backend server language you use? php? javascript (node.js)? or some other?

Comment: i would suggest to use `axios`. Its simple and very usefull for ajax request.

Comment: I'm using javascript right now

Comment: This does not work for POST request. But worked for GET AJAX request.