# How do I get http content from a https website?

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, angular-httpclient

I get "Http failure response for https://www.google.com: 0 Unknown Error" when I request from Secured url.

I am trying to test my ionic/angular mobile app. When I tried with http requests I had problem with Android 9, but with Android 7 was working fine. Anyhow I need to set my backend to public https server. So now I'm testing with https request and none of 7 and 9 Android versions works.

I am using Angular 7 ,

```
"@ionic/angular": "^4.6.1",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.1"
```

I made these small functions in order to make my problem simpler.

inside my html file i have this code:

myFile.html

```
  <ion-button
          (click)="onStartTest()"
  >Click me</ion-button>
  <p id="testme"></p>
```

myFile.page.ts

```
  onStartTest() {
    this.taskService.onTest().subscribe(result => {
      document.getElementById('testme').innerText = 'result ' + result;
      console.log(result);

    }, error => {
      document.getElementById('testme').innerText = error.message;
      console.log('Problem ', error.message);
    });
  }
```

myTask.service.ts

```
  onTest() {
    return this.http.get('https://www.google.com').pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

At first I tried my server's URL but I changed it to "https://www.google.com" just to verify that the backend is correct.

Also I have an interceptors.ts file that I am using it for authentication, but I am not logged in when I execute the onStartTest() function, but im gonna share it anw.

interceptors.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    let newHeaders = req.headers;

    if (token) {
      console.log(token);
      newHeaders = newHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Token ' + token);
      const modified = req.clone({
        headers: newHeaders
      });
      return next.handle(modified);
    } else {
      newHeaders = newHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      const modified = req.clone({
        headers: newHeaders
      });
      return next.handle(modified);
    }
  }
}
```

I think these are the necessary files to share for this problem.
I also tested the url of google with Postman just to be sure that I should get a status 200

[image: Postman GET request https://www.google.com]

I am also aware that there is an "add_header" directive (nginx) that adds 'Allow-access-control-origin' when the response code is 20x or 30x. According to my screenshot with Postman, google is responding with 200 status, but my app still gets status 0 error.

Ignore the first Error. It's a function I use with http when the app begins. Right now im testing https.

[image: Error from google chrome console]

[image: Network status]

I tried superficially to use ionic-native library HTTP but my app totally crashed.

I also execute the command `ionic serve --ssl` but still nothing.

I read somewhere that for secured connection I need a certificate, but I understood that this is a server's work.

I tried to request from Dark Sky from Vanilla JavaScript and it works fine. So there is something wrong with angular/ionic side and not server's.

What am I missing? I really need to fix this problem soon!
I want to send a secured request to an https url and get the appropriate response.

Comment: Google does not respond to CORS requests I'd say

Comment: I thought about that and that's why I tested it with Postman. With postman get a 200 status. Anyhow, I'll try to use another URL but i think that is not the problem since when I used the url from my server I had the exactly same error.

Comment: I used this url from dark sky and still same error, which is https:
https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b66bc3384e22439cafb91f9124f7c5e0/32.000,%2035.000

Comment: Because  this  api does not implement CORS either. Read up about CORS, and there are plenty of SO questions related to that. This is not related to https. Send and OPTIONS request with POSTMAN to check. If your question is 'why cannot I request a http content from a https website', then it's for security reasons. Your error message indicates this clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are trying make an API to an unsecure call (http) location (`http://192....../mobile/tasks)` from a secure origin (`https://localhost:8100`).

This is clearly indicated in your error message and this is not allowed, and has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

Your second problem is that, for testing purposes, you are trying to call a 3rd party `https` ressource from your website. This only works if the 3rd party ressource implement CORS, which is not the case for Google and api.darksky.net. Sending a GET request with Postman is useless, as Postman will not check for CORS headers before displaying the response. If you want to use Postman to check CORS, send an OPTIONS request to these ressources and you'll see that there are no CORS headers

Comment: I am aware for the first error. But Right now I am testing the https function, the second error. 

Good point with the 3rd party https, I didn't know. 

But still I don't fully understand what I can do for CORS. I read the MDN article and ionic for CORS too many times. Most of the answers are saying that it's server's problem and that the server needs to add "access-control-allow-origin" header. I'll try to see what else I can find. In case I don't find anything I will come back to the post. If I do find I will mark this answer.

Comment: Also I want to ask why when i tried it with Vanilla JavaScript i didn't have a CORS error with this 3rd party api? Is it like Postman? Not checking CORS headers ?

Comment: You can only solve it by adding headers if you own the API, otherwise you need to setup a proxy. You will have the same error with plain JS. Press f12 on this page and paste that in the console to verify: `fetch('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b66bc3384e22439cafb91f9124f7c5e0/32.000,%2035.000').then(resp => console.log(resp))`

Comment: I got 
"Access to fetch at 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b66bc3384e22439cafb91f9124f7c5e0/32.000,%2035.000' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: Exactly. That's my point: you get the same error using plain vanillaJS

Comment: So I've been trying it. They also changed the backend. I connect to the network via VPN and then I send http request to the url from mobile and browser and i am getting CORS problem about  'allow-access' headers. But when I try the fetch function you told me, I get status 200 and the response. This is really weird.

Comment: Okay the fact that the fetch method in browser was working but on mobile not was really tricky. It was indeed backend's problem and we had to switch from the Custom CORS method to the library cors-headers of django. Now everything works fine, even the https. So you answer helped us focus to the correct direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are the one who asked, so you do as you please

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is in [MDN - CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API
>   follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using
>   those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the
>   application was loaded from, unless the response from other origins
>   includes the right CORS headers.

This means the back-end I was using needed some more configuration since I was using 'same-origin' policy script. I thought we had it because when we tried from the browser's console to fetch the request it was working fine, but on mobile it wasn't. We had a custom CORS configuration but we changed it to the `django-cors-headers`. Since we switched to `django-cors-headers` I could get correctly the response from HTTP and HTTPs requests.
The other answer and comments were really useful to focus to the right direction.