# static webpage in GCS - API call in java script in html not responding

Tags: javascript, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have static page in gcs bucket and try to invoke API. I am getting any response if I click in authenticated url in gcs bucket which is : https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket_name>/sample.html.
Am I doing anything wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Info</title>
    <script>
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", "http://<static_ip>/api/v1/info?id=12345678");
      request.send();
      request.onload = () => {
        console.log(request);
        if (request.status === 200) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
        } else {
          console.log(`error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}`);
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the console in chrome you can see that you are getting the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mymadpbucket/index.html' was loaded
> over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://%3Cstatic_ip%3E/api/v1/info?id=12345678'. This request has
> been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can't just serve an embedded http content on an https web. This is documented and there are more questions open for this like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

I created this example of a file that could be served from Cloud Storage. You have to configure the cors of your bucked before attempting this. You won't see anything displayed on the browser directly but you will see the image content in the console (pressing F12). I used imgur as a source because I don't know what or how are you trying to serve on that static ip source and because imgur have wide cors to use with Storage.

```
cors.json
[
{
  "origin": ["*"],
  "method": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],
  "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
  "maxAgeSeconds": 100
}
]

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Info</title>
    <script>
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", "https://i.imgur.com/r97IfAU.jpg");
      //request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'https://imgur.com');
      request.send();
      request.onload = () => {
        console.log(request);
        if (request.status === 200) {
          console.log(request.response);
        } else {
          console.log(`error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}`);
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your sending your response before the data can load. Resquest.open() and the send method should come after the the onload call.