# Issue when trying to use Nested routes in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

**main.js**

```html
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import User from "./components/User";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "HelloWorld",
      component: HelloWorld,
      children: [{ path: ":id", name: "User", component: User }]
    }
  ]
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b> id: {{ item.id }}</b>
      <router-link :to="`/HelloWorld/${item.id}`">
        {{ item.title }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <!-- end v-for -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import { router } from "./router";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    router().then((r) => {
      this.items = r.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

codesandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-oq808t?file=/src/main.js

in main.js routing file, if i change from **path:'/'** to **path:'/HelloWorld'** then output is not displaying. Not sure why and where it is linked with api call..

The reason why i changed from path:'/' to path:'/HelloWorld' because path:'/' in my project, it will consider as login page. So tried changing but getting blank screen.

Comment: errors in console? cors? mixed content?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Mixed content blocked" when running an HTTP AJAX operation in an HTTPS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No it is different question

Comment: codesandbox console wont show proper errors, use browser console, can see its showing mixed content error, to fix you need to make your API endpoint https

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just checked in browser also. but no errors.  the way of calling api is wrong i guess.

i am not sure, how to call api with url params

Comment: additional note, make items an array if its an array when resolved, `items: []` and if the API returns an array then either do `this.items = item.data;` or `this.items = this.items.concat(item.data);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you show munch. above mentioned correction is working fine with my code. :)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Can you please tell me one small correction in my code. https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-oq808t?file=/src/main.js

in main.js routing file, if i change from  **path:'/'** to **path:'/HelloWorld'** then output is not displaying

Comment: Because in my case, path:'/' indicates login page...

Comment: If you change it in codesandbox there won't be any handler for `/` so would need to change the URL to `/#/HelloWorld` for it to show anything, also would need to change all the links to `:to="\`/HelloWorld/${item.id}\`"`, or `:to="{ name: 'User', params: { id: item.id } }"` if you want to target the child route using named route

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i tried both the ways, But getting blank page. When i changed to  ""/#/HelloWorld"" and :to="`/HelloWorld/${item.id}`"

Here it is after correction 

https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-oq808t?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: should be `path: "/HelloWorld",` not `path: "/#/HelloWorld",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/HelloWorld/",
      name: "HelloWorld",
      component: HelloWorld,
      children: [{ path: ":id", name: "User", component: User }]
    }
  ]
});
```

to

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/HelloWorld/",
      name: "HelloWorld",
      component: HelloWorld,
      children: [{ path: ":id", name: "User", component: User }]
    }
  ]
});
```

(So, add `mode: history,` to the `router`.)

More on `mode: history` in `Vue Router v3` [here](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)