# Making a get request using JS to retrieve the output of a jenkins job

Tags: javascript, jenkins

I'm trying to retrieve the console output of a jenkins job and am making a get request using javascript but am given an error. Does anyone know how to use Jenkins API to do this?

Specifically trying to do this: "Accessing Progressive Console Output
You can retrieve in-progress console output by making repeated GET requests with a parameter. You'll basically send GET request to this URL (or this URL if you want HTML that can be put into

```
 tag.) The start parameter controls the byte offset of where you start."
```

Here's currently my code without the url:

`const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='url;
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  console.log(Http.responseText)
}`

Here's the console output: The page at "url" was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'url' This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Mixed content blocked" when running an HTTP AJAX operation in an HTTPS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page)

Comment: That was helpful but now I'm getting this error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR